# Strange output with command subtitution using backticks in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, command-substitution

```
echo "testing:"
PROXY_URL="/proxyurl/"
proxyUrlSedEscaped=`echo "$PROXY_URL" | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g'`
echo                     "$PROXY_URL" | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g'
echo "$proxyUrlSedEscaped"

echo "???"
```

The above has the following output:

```
testing:
\/proxyurl\/
&proxyurl&
???
```

Why is the last echo output different from the previous echo output?

This command works correctly via the command line: 
`PROXY_URL="/proxyurl/"; echo "$PROXY_URL" | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g'`, output: `\/proxyurl\/`

Comment: One workaround is `proxyUrlSedEscaped=$(echo "$PROXY_URL" | sed -e 's/[\\/&]/\\&/g')`. And according to http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html: "The $(...) form has superseded backticks for command substitution.".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Per the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) ([and POSIX too](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03)):

> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning except when followed by `$`, `` ` ``, or `\`.

That means that `` `echo "$PROXY_URL" | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g'` `` results in the `sed` command that's executed being `sed -e 's/[\/&]/\&/g'`, because the double backslash has been escaped into a single one. `\&` then makes a literal `&` in sed.

You can use `$(...)`-style command substitution instead to avoid that:

```
proxyUrlSedEscaped=$(echo "$PROXY_URL" | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g')
```

The new-style substitution allows any command with its usual interpretation.

If you must use `` ` `` then the fairly-grotesque double-escape works too:

```
proxyUrlSedEscaped=`echo "$PROXY_URL" | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\\\&/g'`
```

That turns `\\\\` into `\\`, which sed then turns into `\` for you.

Comment: Additionally, the problem is also described in Bash FAQ 082 "Why is $(...) preferred over `...` (backticks)?" : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082